# Axon throwing LockAcquisitionFailedException

Tags: java, spring, axon

I’m using axon framework with spring boot version

```
compile("org.axonframework:axon-spring-boot-starter:4.3.3") {
    exclude group: 'org.axonframework', module: 'axon-server-connector'
}
```

Recently I’ve started noticing certain business workflows halting suddenly and when I checked the logs I found this exception

```
Command 'com.example.MyCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.common.lock.LockAcquisitionFailedException(Failed to acquire lock for aggregate identifier(AGG_ID), maximum attempts exceeded (100))
```

This started occurring suddenly and its getting more frequent with time.

The aggregate is configured to use snapshotting

```
@Bean public SnapshotTriggerDefinition MyAggregateSnapshotTriggerDefinition(Snapshotter snapshotter) { 
   return new EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition(snapshotter, 200); 
}
```

This aggregate only has a few running instances and they remain alive for a very long period of time (years)

I read that this exception is thrown if a process seems to hold a lock on the aggregate for far too long, meanwhile a command requested the lock and timeouted waiting for it.

The aggregate does not hold a big amount of data

```
@Aggregate(snapshotTriggerDefinition = "MyAggregateSnapshotTriggerDefinition")
public class MyAggregate {
   @AggregateIdentifier
   private String aggId;
   private boolean paused;
   private int pausingChangelist;
   private RequestCause pauseCause; //enum
   private Seat seat;
   private Queue<Reservation> reservationQueue;
   private boolean canPauseBuildPool;

  ...

}
```

NONE of commands dispatched to this aggregate are sent in “sendAndWait” mode.

All commands have a small payload and there is no heavy computation being done in the command Handler methods. Its litreally checking some boolean flags and raising events.

The event sourcing handlers on the other hand do some logic.
They manipulate the reservation queue by polling and inserting reservations.

```
@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(CertainEvent event) {
    // poll from queue if not empty
    // raise SeatReservedEvent
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(SeatReservedEvent event) {
    // reserve seat
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(SeatFreedEvent event) {
    //  free the seat 
    // poll from queue
    // if queue not empty -> raise SeatReservedEvent  
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(SeatReservationQueuedEvent event) {
    // add to queue
}
```

The weird thing as well, I checked other posts where this same exception is thrown and they seems all to have the exact same error message but mine is the only that has a different number of attempts (100)

```
LockAcquisitionFailedException: 
Failed to acquire lock for aggregate identifier(AGG_ID), 
maximum attempts exceeded (2147483647)
```

I read the code of the PessimisticLockFactory and was able to understand that this number (2147483647) represent the number of times a process tried to acquire the lock on an aggregate.

Why is **100** only in my case? (NO extra config was added from my side)

How can I solve this issue? how can I monitor the locks on the aggregate? how to know what process aquired the token and wouldn’t release it?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "they remain alive for a very long period of time (years)"? I assume you mean they are not marked as deleted but asking just to be sure.

Comment: @MilenDyankov yes, I added that bit of info to say that the aggregate will have a big amount of events. Thats why we are doing snapshots

Comment: @MilenDyankov how can I increase the timeout or the number of attempts? would it help also if I reduce the snapshot threshold?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this exception is thrown when the Aggregate is locked (because of some expensive operation perhaps?) and another thread is trying to lock it as well.

Basically your Aggregate is your boundary meaning no concurrent operations will ever happen on it. For it to work, it has to be locked as soon as some thread starts working on it. The next threads will go on a queue and will try to acquire a lock from time to time and give up after some time (this is the exception you are getting).

For the logic, you can check the [lock](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/messaging/src/main/java/org/axonframework/common/lock/PessimisticLockFactory.java#L260) method.
For the default values, you can have a look at the [Builder](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/messaging/src/main/java/org/axonframework/common/lock/PessimisticLockFactory.java#L158-L160) default values.

To the question why it is happening, from your description, seems like your `@EventSourcingHandler`s are doing "too much". That is already a code smell for me as `@EventSourcingHandler`s should never apply new Events! They react to Events from the past and they should not 'write new history'.

On the other hand, perhaps your `@CommandHandler`s should be checking business logic and applying new Events, what is the normal use case for it.

---

Edit1:

There is no docmentation around it but I can try to give you some idea of how to do that. First of all, recently a new [PR](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/pull/1992) was merged which makes things easier and I am going to use that to explain it.

In this case, you need to provide a `@Bean` of type `LockFactory` with your desired values. After that, you can set this on the `@Aggregate` as your `lockFactory`, something like this:

```java
@Bean
public LockFactory myLockFactory() {
    // your lock factory code and configs here
}
```

```java
@Aggregate(lockFactory = "myLockFactory")
class MyAggregate {
    // your Aggregate
}
```

KR,

Comment: Hello, do you know why it attempted the acquisition for 100 times and in other usecases it tried 2147483647 times?

Comment: I agree on the part of the event sourcing handlers raising events is confusing and a bad practice

Comment: I don't... default values are `acquireAttempts = 6000` and `lockAttemptTimeout = 10` while the `maximumQueued` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (the 2147483647 you saw somewhere). This is where the confusion could come from.

Comment: I checked the code for the class PessimisticLockFactory and the value for acquireAttempts is 100 and lockAttemptTimeout is 600. Is there a way I can increase it?

Comment: Yes, you can configure that... you need to provide your own `(Pessimistic)LockFactory` and use that on the `EventSourcingRepository$Builder#lockFactory` method.

Comment: Is there documentation I can follow?

Comment: The config suggested above is not straight forward to implement. Is there any documentation that details how to configure the timeout?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a pseudo-code on how to do that... hope it helps further! But mentioning again, you should better check your `CommandHandler` and/or `EventSourcingHandler` as they shouldn't take that long anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> Why is 100 only in my case? (NO extra config was added from my side)

It seems there was a bug in `4.3.x` and earlier versions. The message shows the `maximumQueued` and not the `acquireAttempts`. [This commit](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/commit/8e9572eee353ec6ef60d6ae572d238d6f5218d85) fixes it, so if you upgrade to a recent version of Axon Framework you should see the correct value.

Comment: I checked the decompiled class PessimisticLockFactory and the logged variable is indeed the acquireAttempts. Meaning the code already contains the fix.

Comment: Do you advise increasing the number of acquire attempts? if yes how can we do so?